# Add DistanceFeatureQueryBuilder to Criteria with Elasticsearch Java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using `Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.2.3` and I build my Query using Criteria in the following way:

```
Criteria criteria = ...
Query query = new CriteriaQuery(criteria)
    .setPageable(paging);

SearchHits<Content> hits = elasticsearchRestTemplate
    .search(query, Person.class);
```

I want to add `DistanceFeatureQueryBuilder` to the query before searching. I can create it in this way but don't know how to add it to the query:

```
    DistanceFeatureQueryBuilder distanceFeatureQueryBuilder = new DistanceFeatureQueryBuilder("date",
    new Origin("now"), "1d");
```

How can I use both at the same time? I want to use Criteria to build the conditions and use distance_feature in the same query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, there is currently no integration of the [specialized queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.13/specialized-queries.html) into the `Criteria` API.